# Hashtable and sort it and show only the n topest values

Tags: c#

The format of output is like :

```
  0.8765432
  0.7654323
  1.0987234
.......
```

I must get the result like this:

```
1    1.0987234
2    0.8765432
3    0.7654323
...
```

I wrote the below script to store my data in hashtable and sort it .I have to sort(descending) it based on the value and extract only the n toppest values(key and value).

```
    if (sc >= 0 && sc <= 89395)
                    {
                        for (int z = 0; z <= 1143600; z++)
                        {
                            dotproduct(sc, z); // is a function to multiply to float
                            hashtable.Add(z, result);
                        }
                        SortedDictionary<int, float> dict = new SortedDictionary<int, float>(hashtable);
                        dict.OrderByDescending(x => x.Key).Take(n);
                        foreach (int key in dict)
                        {
                            System.Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}: {1}", key, dict[key]));
                        }
                    }
```

I have two questions:

1. Is the method that i use to make hashtable and sort correct?
2. How to extract the n topest value to show?

Comment: Why don't you use a SortedDictionary (or Dictionary) right away? These types are type-safe.

Comment: Sorry @Markus ,I had a mistake. I used the hashtable since i don't have any integer (please check the format of data again) as key.That's why I use hashtable to generate the key for each value.

Comment: I`m not sure whether I understand your code fully. Where does `result` come from? Later on, you have a `SortedDictionary<int, float>`, but use `string key` in the foreach loop. What do you want to accomplish? Do you only want to collect some floats, take the largest numbers and display them like `1. <largest float> 2. <2nd largest float ...`?

Comment: Can you post the full code, please?

Comment: Result is the output of dotproduct which is integer. dotproduct must repeat for 1143600 times and the result must be saved in aray or table. this results are only scores while I need to sort the scores with their key. that's why I used hashtable @Markus  . BTW I edited more explanation in my question. please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based upon your comments, I suggest that you can also use a simple `List<float>` (if the result of dotproduct is a float). A `SortedDictionary<int, float>` wouldn't make sense, as you only insert the index of the loop and the result of dotproduct. So a `List<float>` serves the same purpose and requires less memory. If you later want to know the result of the 3rd run, just access the indexer of the list, like `var resultFor3rdRun = list[2]`.

As you write, the original index is important when outputting the data. You have to store this index before; you can do this using an overload of the Linq `Select` extension method that provides the index. Afterwards, you can sort them in descending order and take the number of items that you want to show (e.g. top 10):

```
if (sc >= 0 && sc <= 89395)
{
    var results = new List<float>(1143600); // Specify number of items upfront for better performance
    for (int z = 0; z <= 1143600; z++)
    {
        results.Add(dotproduct(sc, z)); // is a function to multiply to float
    }
    foreach(var resultWithIndex in results
        .Select((x, index) => new { Result = x, Index = index})
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Result)
        .Take(10))
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}: {1}", 
            resultWithIndex.Index, 
            resultWithIndex.Result));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response @Markus. Maybe I couldn't explain my question clearly. when I get the the output it is only float (I don't have their index). But when I wanted to sort it, I need their index to. for example, When I get the output and "1.5462790657" is in the row or index 57, when i sort it,it must be something like "57 1.5462790657" . Based on my understanding from your script,it generates index for sorted data while I need the orginal one (index before sorting)

Comment: @user3328039: Thanks for clarifying; I've updated my answer again and fixed a small issue in SortDescending.

Comment: Thanks much for the modification @Markus